# Merge all values of array in a dictionary

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a dictionary of `var tags = [String:[String]]()`. When returning the values to the REST endpoint I need to merge all the values in `[String]` array. Can I do something with using

```
self.tags.map { $0.value }
```

But no clue how to get a single array using all the values arrays from dictionary.

Comment: You want to use something like: `yourDictionary.values.flatMap { $0 }` or `yourDictionary.flatMap { $0.value }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do that using `flatMap`

```
var tags = [String:[String]]()
tags["1"] = ["2","3"]
tags["2"] = ["4","5"]

let arr = tags.values.flatMap{$0}
```

OR

```
let arr = tags.flatMap(\.value)
```

Prints

```
print(arr) // ["2","3","4","5"]
```

Comment: `tags.flatMap(\.value)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flatMap` to achieve this:

```
var tags   = [String:[String]]()
var values = tags.flatMap { $0.value }
// or using keypath
var values = tags.flatMap(\.value)
```

Or use `flatMap` on values like this:

```
var values = tags.values.flatMap{$0}
```

Comment: This is not your original post. This has been edited after jawadAli posted his answer

Comment: It was not after, I was editing while it got posted. I was trying it out in playgrounds.

Comment: He wouldn't post that answer if you had originally posted this. Anyway just a note your first post was `tags.mapValues { $0.reduce([], +) }` It doesn't show in history because of the 5 minutes allowance]